# add image to photo gallery on the android emulator

Tags: android, addition, gallery, photo

How should I add image to photo gallery on the android emulator?
now I have a android code that opens the gallery and ask the user to choose a photo from the gallery.
I tried to drag and drop some photos onto the android emulator window but when I access the gallery from my android code they are not showing up.
[image]

```
public class GalleryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
    Uri imageUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
                    imageUri = data.getData();
                    imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
            }
    }
```

}

Comment: Cold boot your emulator again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to open the `Device File Explorer` and upload an image to `sdcard/DCIM`

[image: Android Studio]

Don't forget to add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Have you tried adding `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in your manifest?